# Check if Google Pay is available with JS

Tags: javascript, api, stripe-payments, google-pay

There is a system called Engaging Networks where the system provides payment methods like Apple Pay or Google Pay. I would like to show/hide the relevant payment button whether the payment type is available or not.

I know that I can check Apple Pay simply with `window.ApplePaySession` but I can't see how to check Google Pay availability.

I can see the request has been sent to https://pay.google.com/gp/p/ui/pay, but basically that's it.

Is there any way to check this?

Comment: Isn’t this the exact purpose of [`isReadyToPay()`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#isReadyToPay)?

Comment: Probably, but can't see how to call it. I didn't actually called the API, so I was wondering how to just check it, for example with console log.

Comment: ... and this Engaging Networks system uses Stripe for payments.

Comment: If it’s handled by an external system/Stripe, can you add just a bit of color to elaborate on why it’s relevant for you to know when Google Pay is available? Shouldn’t Stripe handle showing/hiding the controls for each payment type?

Comment: Because I have a pre-selection where I need to show the available payment methods :(

Answer (score 2):

As called out by @esqew, here is an example of how to call [`isReadyToPay`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#isReadyToPay):

```js
function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const client = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
    environment: 'TEST',
    merchantInfo: {
      merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
      merchantName: 'Demo Merchant',
    },
  });
  
  const readyToPayOptions = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: [
      {
        type: 'CARD',
        parameters: {
          allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
          allowedCardNetworks: ['MASTERCARD', 'VISA'],
        },
        tokenizationSpecification: {
          type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
          parameters: {
            gateway: 'example',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  
  client.isReadyToPay(readyToPayOptions).then(result => console.log('Is ready to pay: ', result));
}
```

```html
<script
  async
  src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
  onload="onGooglePayLoaded()">
</script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`